# unable to configure apprtc.appspot with own url

Tags: python, google-bigquery, webrtc, apprtcdemo

This is the error I get when I try to configure apprtc with my own url. I tried to set up my own Turn Server and also tried to give a client url but it still did not work .

```
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/esuioswebrtc/datasets/prod/tables/analytics/insertAll?alt=json returned "Not Found: Table esuioswebrtc:prod.analytics">
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~esuioswebrtc/2.382445032671238924/apprtc.py", line 503, in post
    result = add_client_to_room(self.request, room_id, client_id, is_loopback)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~esuioswebrtc/2.382445032671238924/apprtc.py", line 373, in add_client_to_room
    host=request.host)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~esuioswebrtc/2.382445032671238924/analytics.py", line 114, in report_event
    analytics.report_event(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~esuioswebrtc/2.382445032671238924/analytics.py", line 94, in report_event
    body=obj).execute()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~esuioswebrtc/2.382445032671238924/third_party/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~esuioswebrtc/2.382445032671238924/third_party/apiclient/http.py", line 723, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/esuioswebrtc/datasets/prod/tables/analytics/insertAll?alt=json returned "Not Found: Table esuioswebrtc:prod.analytics">
```

Comment: that's a BigQuery name. Do you have a table "analytics" under the dataset "prod" in the project "esuioswebrtc"?

Comment: @patrica yes esuioswebrtc is the project name , I am not familiar with BigQuery ,i dint create any table under Analytics ,I am use apprtc code to test my url

Comment: your url seems to be trying to insert data into a BigQuery table. Maybe you need access to the table, or simply need to create it. Go to https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/welcome/esuioswebrtc" and create the needed stuff. Or it may simply be you need to enable the API from your developer console at https://console.developers.google.com/project/esuioswebrtc" under "APIs & auth" then APIs. Find BigQuery and turn the slider to On

Comment: My BigQuery flag is already on green ,I enabled it and regarding the table do i need to write a query for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `insertAll` to stream data into a table, you must first create the table and give it the schema you will use.

You should pre-create the table out of band from your streaming insert process, since the rate limits on these apis differ drastically. For scenarios where you stream data into daily tables, we recommend that you pre-create the next few days of tables on some sort of cron process so they are ready for data before you need to stream into them.

Comment: I created a dataset and created a table in https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries and enabled billing for it in developer console and it started working .